# Getting Download URL for Firebase Storage Files

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-storage

I have a mobile app and it requires Firebase sign-up to backup / restore custom user data in Firebase. I am wondering if authorised user can get somehow the url of his own storage file and download it to his computer.

Comment: You can always store your image in your userDefault or cache, give it a key and access it.

Comment: Its not an image, its ad backup file and I dont want user to download it to his computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a user is authorized to access a specific file, that user is authorized to access that file using any means. It doesn't matter whether that is through your app or through another app or API.

There is no way to limit access to the user's files to only your app.

Comment: How he can reach the authorized url with its token? Because we dont use any api or web component. I mean I just need user to not to be able to download stored item. How else he can authorise except my app?

Comment: If they are authorized to access the file, they can use the API to [get a download URL for the file](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files#generate_a_download_url). Alternatively they can get the URL from your app and then open it on their desktop machine. Note that this sounds like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Instead of focusing on the solution you have in mind, you'll probably get better help if you describe the problem.